# Проблемы с добавлением шрифтов

Tags: java, android, xml

У меня такая проблема – хочу добавить свой шрифт в приложение и когда делаю это программно, то есть:

```
TextView twLabel = findViewById (R.id.label);
Typeface tfLabel = Typeface.createFromAsset (getAssets (), "fonts/play_bold.ttf");
twLabel.setTypeface (tfLabel);
```

Все работает отлично. А вот через разметку, то есть через стили у меня проблема. Я посмотрел, как это делать – в папке res создать папку font, загрузить шрифты и подключить эти шрифты в стилях, но вот в чем проблема – как только я создаю папку font в папке res мне выдает ошибку: **"aapt: invalid resource directory name"**

/storage/emulated/0/AppProjects/MyApp/app/src/main/res/font/play_bold.ttf

А код, точнее стиль вот так

```
android:fontFamily="@font/play_bold"
```

Comment: Вы пишете, что создали директорию `font`. При этом в коде у вас директория `fonts`. Нет ли проблемы с этим? [Уточните](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1506050/edit) в вопросе, укажите полный путь до файла `play_bold.ttf`.

Comment: Вы показали код, который у вас работает отлично, но забыли показать код, в котором у вас проблема. Покажите код вашей разметки или стилей, как вы обращаетесь ко шрифтам? [Добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1506050/edit) недостающую информацию непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: Смотрите какая у меня ситуация: когда я добавляю шрифты программно, то есть кодом, приведенным выше, эти шрифты находятся у меня в папке "main/assets/fonts", а когда я хочу их получить через разметку, в уроках сказано, что нужно создать папку "font" в папке "main/res/" и вот когда я ее создаю у меня выскакивает ошибка. А на счёт кода – с ним у меня проблем нету, так как кода нету. Я не могу создать его поскольку мне выдает ошибку.

Comment: Покажите, какой код вы пытаетесь создать. И напишите в вопросе, где, в какой директории у вас дежит файл. Желательно полный путь до файла, вот так: `app/src/.../play_bold.ttf`. Файл лежит в font или в fonts?

Comment: Добавил ответ...

Comment: Проверьте расположение файла. У вас файл лежит в `app/src/res/font/play_bold.ttf`, а должен лежать в `app/src/main/res/font/play_bold.ttf`.

Comment: Да, он у меня там и находится. Я просто поспешил с ответом

Comment: Тогда обновите ваш вопрос, укажите в вопросе полный путь, по которому у вас лежит файл с шрифтами. Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите кнопку "[править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1506050/edit)", которая находится под вопросом, который вы задали.

Comment: Указал полный путь

Comment: Чтобы заработала конструкция `@font/play_bold`, необходимо положить файл `play_bold.ttf` в директорию `app/src/main/res/font` относительно **корня вашего проекта**. Например, если у вас **проект на компьютере** находится в директории `С:/MyAndroidApp`, то файл с шрифтом должен находиться в `С:/MyAndroidApp/app/src/main/res/font/play_bold.ttf`.

Comment: Сделал все как вы сказали, но ошибка не пропала

Comment: Может есть какой-то другой, пусть даже по сложнее способ? Главное, чтобы я мог использовать шрифты через разметку, то есть стили

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю других способов, это основной подход работы с ресурсами в Андроид.

Comment: Просто я читал, что есть какой-то способ написать класс на java и создать разметку семейства шрифтов и что-то в этом духе, но, так как у меня сейчас проблемы с компьютером и приходится работать на телефоне, а времени подробно изучать у меня, увы – нет, я отложил это изучение на потом. Вы, если я не ошибаюсь – "Вадим", хорошо знаете java и андроид-разработку в целом. Помогите такому дураку, как я стать немного умнее в этой отрасли.

Comment: Я опубликовал новый ответ.  Нет ничего более простого, чем добавить свой шрифт в Андроид-проект. Совершенно непонятно, зачем вам такие сложные решения и какой-то там класс.

Comment: Просто я сейчас работаю через AIDE  и у меня нет другого выхода...

Comment: В чем проблема? Сформулируйте. Добавьте необходимую информацию в вопрос. Или задайте новый вопрос. Ваш вопрос по разработке под Андроид или про функции какой-то определенной IDE? В IDE нет функции создать файл в проекте?

Comment: Stackoverflow это не чат, а сайт вопросов-ответов. Вы четко формулируете вопрос — вам дают четкий ответ. Столько написали в комментариях, а вопрос не актуализировали. Переформулируйте.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создаем новый Android-проект
2. В проекете создаем директорию `app/src/main/res/font`
3. В директорию `font` кладем файл `my_font.ttf`
4. Все готово! Теперь можно использовать шрифт в `TextView`:

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

Результат:

[image: скриншот]

Вы можете посмотреть минималистичный [демо-проект](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1506050) и непосредственно [коммит](https://github.com/sirekanian/q1506050/commit/ef683795f71084d60b490156f25af914edf13c0d), в котором добавляется кастомный шрифт.